# Configured Network Settings do not apply after purging Xfce on Debian 10

Tags: debian

I have a newer install of Debian 10 with Apache/MariaDB/PHP installed.  I installed it from the disk with Xfce installed but realized soon after that I didn't need that.  I ran this command to remove it:

```
dpkg -l | grep .xfce. | awk '{print $2}' | xargs sudo apt-get purge -V --auto-remove -yy
```

After running that command I rebooted and it seems that Xfce is gone. My problem is though my networking doesn't work on restart.  I added this to my /etc/network/interfaces file:

```
# The primary network interface
iface ens192 inet static
address 10.0.2.28
gateway 10.0.2.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 10.0.2.255
network 10.0.2.0
```

after that I ran `systemctl restart networking` but nothing changes.  Nothing changes after a restart either.  Actually the interface is status "DOWN" after a reboot.  I can also use `sudo dhclient ens192` to temporarily grab dhcp but I can't get it to persist on a reboot. I can also use `ip a add {ip_addr/mask} dev {interface}` to add the network settings to get connectivity but it doesn't persist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a line:

```
# The primary network interface
auto ens192
iface ens192 inet static
address 10.0.2.28
gateway 10.0.2.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 10.0.2.255
network 10.0.2.0
```

Without `auto <interface-name>`, which in your case is `ens192`, the interface won't come up at boot.

Also, in case you haven't, make sure that the `networking` service is enabled.

Comment: That worked thank you.